# how to drawing chess board using extend view but not the all view

Tags: java, android

I try to draw a chess board  using a canvas but the view  recovers all 
the entity and don't see my buttons of the activitymain xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonnew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonnewgradient"
        android:text="@string/Buttonnewtext"
        android:textColor="#dde41c"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>



public class BoardClass extends View {

   public  BoardClass(Context context)
    { super(context);}
}
```

The mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     BoardClass board;
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         board = new BoardClass(this);
        setContentView(board);
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) . Your custom view should be included in activity layout and then you can use that tag like you do with all the other views: `setContentView(R.layout.main_layout)`.